# jquery template inside AIR app throws security violation

Tags: jquery, air, aptana, jquery-templates

I'm using Aptana studio to build an AIR app from sample jquery code. The sample code uses template plugin, code detailed here - http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-tmpl/  "A tree view, using recursive nested {{tmpl}} tags."

The initial rendering works fine but when i click on the samples node to expand, it throws a security exception -  Error: Adobe AIR runtime security violation for JavaScript code in the application security sandbox (Function constructor)

Debugger points out that the violation is in the update call on the parent template.

```
        $("#samplesList").delegate(".toggle", "click", function(){
            /* Toggle expanded property on data, then update rendering */
            var tmplItem = $.tmplItem(this);
            tmplItem.data.expanded = !tmplItem.data.expanded;
*>>>            tmplItem.update(); >>> VOILATION HERE* 
        }).delegate(".folderItem", "click", function(){
            alert($.tmplItem(this).data.description);
        });
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the only solution is to precompile the templates at the beginning (in document ready). It's a good practice and saves execution time anyways.

List of all the operations that result in security violation can be found [here](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Avoid_JavaScript_security_errors_in_the_AIR_applic-8083.html). Templating (also, underscore.js `_.template` function) violates the Adobe policy by using `Function` constructor.